# Correct co-variance notation?

Tags: probability, notation, covariance

Whilst proving something for $var(aX+bY+c)$, we are given the result

$var(X+Y)=var(Y)+var(X)+2cov(X+Y)$ and $cov(aX+bY)=abcov(X+Y)$

What I am not sure is that when I simplified things down, I get the co-variant term to be as:

$2abcov(X+Y)$

Is that the same as $2abcov(X,Y)$.I think it is correct as it should just mean the co-variance is a function of 2 variables without constants. I am not sure as I have also seen something like this $cov(aX,bY)=abcov(X,Y)$ written as a rule.

Comment: "$\mathrm{Cov}(aX+bY)=ab\mathrm{Cov}(X+Y)$" -- this doesn't make sense. You cannot take the covariance of one thing.

Comment: @MeesdeVries So, was there like maybe a typo from where I got this result from?

Comment: I think the second equation is supposed to be $cov(aX,bY)=ab\, cov(X,Y)$.